# Geodesic distances and physical measurements in MeshLab

Tags: distance, volume, area, meshlab

I would like to measure geodesic distances interactively on MeshLab. I couldn't find how to do this in the software neither looking online. I see that there is a function "colorize by geodesic distance from a given point" but colors the mesh and do not give the distance values themselves.

Other distances that I'm also interested in measuring are surface area and volume of meshes. I couldn't find functions to compute those either.

I'm using MeshLab 2016.12 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Colorize by geodesic distance from a given point" saves the actual distance values in the multipurpose scalar "vertex quality" (vq) field. If you save the resulting mesh as a ply file you can view the actual values (for example, save as an ascii ply file and open with a text editor). Not really interactive, but possible.

Volume and surface area can be found with the "Compute Geometric Measures" filter, as well as many other parameters.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the geodesic distance filter features. With regard of the "Compute Geometric Measures" filter, I wasn't able to locate it because I was using MeshLab from the Ubuntu app manager. This and other options are only available when MeshLab is installed with snap.